# System.Text.Json object array deserialization

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, system.text.json

I'm trying to deserialize JSON such as this:

```js
{ "Parameters": [ 1, "2", true, false, null ] }
```

using `System.Text.Json` serializer. Target class looks like this:

```cs
public class Payload {
    public object[] Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

Parameters are always primitive values like numbers, strings, booleans, etc.
But looks like `System.Text.Json` populates my `Parameters` array with
`JsonElement` values instead of plain scalar values. Here is the code sample:

```cs
var payload = new Payload {
    Parameters = new object[] {
        1, "2", true, false, null
    }
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload);
// result: {"Parameters":[1,"2",true,false,null]}

var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Payload>(json);
// result: deserialized.Parameters are all `JsonElement` values
```

The code that consumes the `Payload` class doesn't depend on `System.Text.Json`,
it is serializer-agnostic. Is there a way to deserialize the array of objects
using `System.Text.Json` and get back plain scalar values instead of `JsonElement`s?

Comment: This behavior is explained exactly in [Deserialize inferred types to object properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#deserialize-inferred-types-to-object-properties) article. Did you try to follow it and write own `JsonConverter<object>`?

Comment: Thanks Pavel, looks like I've missed this article in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An indication how it can be done. Will deserialize test data correctly if we can live with int64 for numbers, but still just a POC.

```
public class ObjectConverter : JsonConverter<object>
{
  public override object Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
  {
    return reader.TokenType switch
    {
      JsonTokenType.Number => reader.GetInt64(),
      JsonTokenType.String => reader.GetString(),
      JsonTokenType.True => reader.GetBoolean(),
      JsonTokenType.False => reader.GetBoolean(),
      _ => null
    };
  }

   public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
 }

 public class Payload {
   public object[] Parameters { get; set; }
 }

 var payload = new Payload
 {
   Parameters = new object[] { 1, "2", true, false, null }
 };

 var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload);
 var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
 serializeOptions.Converters.Add(new ObjectConverter());
 var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Payload>(json, serializeOptions);
```